# Listview android values mixed up in the scroll

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm using an ArrayAdapter to display items in my Listview, but when i scroll the order of the items change, i guess the pb is in the getView method, I tried to add a viewHolder to resolve this but nothing changed, my Listview still mixed up

Here my adapter :

```
public class AdpaterFeed extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    String[] data;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Helper helper;

    public AdpaterFeed(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
        this.helper = Helper.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txt =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
            viewHolder.webview = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (getItem(position) != null) {

            if (getItem(position).contains("<img")) {

                viewHolder.webview.loadData(helper.rss[position], "text/html", "UTF-8");

            } else {

                viewHolder.txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(helper.title[position]));
                viewHolder.webview.loadData(helper.rss[position], "text/html", "UTF-8");
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt;
        WebView webview;

    }

}
```

Do anyone can help me ?

Comment: Can you post the code of ```getItem``` method? Do you change the collection that is used by the adapter?

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov i didnt implement the getItem method, it's a method that u can use on the adapter

Comment: Not related, but for proper interpretation of `layout_params` in your XML `layoutResourceId`, you should use the inflate method with the parent: `inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false)`

Comment: @Joffrey i didn' really understand you , can you plz explain more ?

Comment: You use `inflate(layoutResourceId, null)` (with a null parent). When inflating a layout, the inflater reads your XML attributes, and some of them start with `layout_`. These attributes' actual values depend on the parent at the moment of inflation. If you specify no parent (null), then the inflater won't know what value to give them, in particular `layout_width` and `layout_height`. The overloaded version of the method that I gave you allows to provide the parent without actually adding your view as a child.

Comment: @Joffrey i saw everywhere that i need to use a viewHolder to resolve this , but it doesnt worked for me do u have any idea ?

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I said it was unrelated, but this could have caused visual problems. Have a look at my answer for your original question's problem. The view holder is a pattern that makes the code easier to understand, but it doesn't change the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update: with the OP's precision in the comments, I believe the problem comes from the way the webviews are loaded. Maybe you should find a way to control the loading with AsyncTasks, and make sure you match the right view to the right content.

---

Maybe your problem lies in the fact that you don't erase the text in the first part of that if:

```
if (getItem(position).contains("<img")) {
    viewHolder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE); // maybe you want this here?
    viewHolder.webview.loadData(getItem(position), "text/html", "UTF-8");
} else {
    viewHolder.text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // and compensate here
    viewHolder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(helper.title[position]));
    viewHolder.webview.loadData(getItem(position), "text/html", "UTF-8");
}
```

If you have different kinds of items (with text or with image), maybe you should take a look at the view types in adapters. This is a very important feature allowing to have different layouts for different types of view.

---

UNRELATED:
Regarding this code:

```
TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
WebView wv = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
viewHolder.txt = text;
viewHolder.webview = wv;
```

I find it cleaner (and definitely shorter) to skip the local variables:

```
viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
viewHolder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
viewHolder.webview = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by mixed up? Why don't you set a text for elements having an image? If you don't override that text, you will keep the former text (the one before recycling the view on scroll).

Comment: im using the webview instead of the textView for the image , because my imgs they cant be load only in webview , they are html5 img . And mixed up i mean when i scroll the content of row change in random way

Answer (score 0):

Use the view holder concept as written in below sample...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

        TextView programName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.programName);
        TextView programTime = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.programTime);
        TextView programState = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.programState);
        ImageView programImage =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.programImage);



        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.p_Name = programName;
        viewHolder.p_Time = programTime;
        viewHolder.p_State = programState;
        viewHolder.p_Image = programImage;

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.p_Name.setText(values.programNames.get(position));
    viewHolder.p_Time.setText(values.programTimes.get(position));
    new imageDownload(programImage).execute(values.programImageUrls.get(position)); 


    return convertView;
}
```

And the View holder class look like this

```
public static class ViewHolder {
 TextView p_Name;
 TextView p_Time;
 TextView p_State;
 ImageView p_Image;
```

}

Hope this would help you.